# Android mapview live online overlay items

Tags: android, download, android-mapview

I want to make an app like Waze. What is the best way to implement live moving Overlay items like in Waze did (e.g. moving cars). What methods give best performance to show live moving overlay items? Maybe someone has experience with these things can shed some light?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks!